# Copy a row from a weekly tab into each day's tab using the date in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I work in a clinic and we are trying to go paperless. We have a new payement system online and we are using a google sheet to follow if stuff is payed, results, sent, etc. I've managed to color code my cells with conditional formatting, but can't manage my next wish:

We would enter the patient information in the tab WEEK and select the date of the appointment in the next cell. I'd love for the system to copy that whole line into the tab for that date and for the formatting to follow. The point is to have a global outlook on the week, what payments are in, where we're at with results, ect, but that we could check day by day as well for a narrower view and to make it easier to check. So when I check a box on either the weekly or daily page, it would do it in both tabs.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet and show us the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to edit the daily tabs, just view it, you can use a Query formula to import the data with any given date, onto its appropriate tab. Take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/JjO0SZ1iBlU) and see if it helps.

You can also use a script by going to Tools > Script Editor. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261647/google-apps-script-copy-rows-from-one-sheet-containing-todays-date-into-anoth) to a previous similar question or [this post](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/41759938.html) may help.